# should I use PUT to create a resource with a known id (e.g.: email)

Tags: rest

I believe to have read some time ago that creating a resource when the id is known (e.g.: `email`) should be done using a PUT on that resource.

E.g.: 
`PUT /user/chris@example.com`

is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct to use

```
PUT resource/{id} --> 204 No Content
```

when the `id` of the resource is being specified by the client and the operation is idempotent. The operation is idempotent if doing it two or more times in a row has the same effect as doing it once.

If you use `POST`, you  usually do not provide a client identifier. Instead the server chooses its own identifier and informs the client of the created resource's location by sending a `201 Created` response with a `Location` header.

```
POST resource     --> 201 Created
                      Location: /resource/7
```

Comment: idempotence only covers domain model state correct? Say as part of business logic an email is send to the user when the `user` is created through put. Updating the user through put would result in the same exact domain-model but this time the app will not send an email. I feel this would still be correct. What do you think?

Comment: @Geert-Jan Yes, that's correct.  You would not send multiple emails.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's correct to use `PUT` to create a resource with a known URI. `PUT` asks the server to replace the resource at the target URI with the resource representation in the payload, so you have to know the target URI. However, keep in mind that `PUT` requires a complete representation, so if you're creating or updating a resource with an incomplete representation, you should use `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what more correctly to do it throught POST on new url and create if thid id does not exists.
Because PUT method is idempotent (e. g. if you send one request many time - result would be same).